# Increment a number on each replace in javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, numbers, increment, str-replace

I want to increment a number each time string.replace() replace a sub-string. for example in:

```js
var string = "This is this";
var number = 0;
string.replace("is", "as");
```

When string.replace first is of `This` number becomes `1`, then for second is of `is` number becomes `2` and finally for last is of `this` number becomes `3`.
Thanks in advance...! :-)

Comment: You mean you want to count the replacements ?

Comment: You can use a [function as a second parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)  to do that.

Comment: `string.replace("is", "as");` will only replace the first occurrence though. Are you planning to call `replace` multiple times?

Comment: @FelixKling No I don't want to call the replace multiple times.

Comment: @ForguesR But second parameter uses to replace the text, and I also want to replace the text as well

Answer (score 20):

You can pass a function to `.replace()` and return the value. You also need to use a global regex to replace all instances.

```js
var string = "This is this";
var number = 0;

document.body.textContent = string.replace(/is/g, function() {
    return ++number;
});
```

Comment: But I also want to replace the text

Comment: @EMM: just return the replacement.

Comment: @FelixKling And what about this:     
    var string = "This is this";
    var number = 0;
    string.replace(/is/g, function() {
      number++;
      return "as $1 as";
    });
    alert(number);

Comment: @FelixKling See My Answer below

Comment: @EMM: matches are passed as arguments to the function. Please read the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @EMM: You're not describing clearly what you want. What is `$1` supposed to be? If you want it to be the value of `number` then use string concatenation like normal. `return "as" + number + "as";`

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```js
var string = "This is this";
var number = 0;
string.replace(/is/g, function() {
  number++;
  return "as";
});
alert(number);
```